# Interactive 3D model on the page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, three.js

I'm a beginner and I don't understand why my model is not displayed. Its dimensions are 0.252, 0.279, 0.243. I changed its size and scaling - does not help. The model loads successfully to the page, but there is no display.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
// Creating a scene and a camera   var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1,            1000);
// Creating a renderer  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
// Get the container and add the renderer to the pagevar container = 
  document.getElementById("model-container");
  if (container) {
     container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

// Creating a model loader
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

// Loading the model from a file
loader.load('C:/Users/AloneWasser/Desktop/Diplom/asd/Etan.obj', function (object) {
// Scaling the model
object.scale.set(0.252, 0.279, 0.243);
// Adding a model to the scene
scene.add(object);         },    function (xhr) {     console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% загружено');     },     function (error) {     console.log('Ошибка загрузки модели', error);     }     );

// Position the camera and set the direction of view of the model
camera.position.z = 10;

// Updating the scene and rendering it
function animate() {
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
 }
animate();
});
```

Comment: Please reformat your question to be readable. You can use code fences (three backticks on a new line) around your code to make it appear formatted correctly. Also please reformat your title to succinctly address what issue you're having. And please don't forget to include more information about your issue in the body of your post. Here are some guidelines to follow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Pls follow @Andria's advice. It's impossible for us to help you when we can't understand anything due to the improper formatting. After you format, we will try our best to help you.

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example so we could play with it around?